# Instruments Leaks - Not showing my source code

Tags: iphone, memory, instruments, memory-leaks

I am attempting to analyze an iPhone application using the Leaks application and everything appears to be working fine, except for when I try to view detailed information about a particular memory leak. Leaks does not appear to be loading my source code.  Looking at the stack view on the right, I can see calls that reference iPhone frameworks, but anything that is referencing source code that I've written is empty.  The screenshot below illustrates my point.  The blocks that are light blue should be referencing my source code.  Has anyone ever had this problem? Is Leaks just not finding my source code/symbols correctly?  Thanks!

EDIT: I am compiling the app using the 'Device - iPhone OS 2.2' with the Debug configuration. I launch Leaks by selecting Run->Start With Performance Tool->Leaks from within Xcode. How would one go about 'making the symbol files available' for Leaks?

[image]
<sub>(source: [andrewgarrison.com](http://www.andrewgarrison.com/forum/leaks_nosource.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove any non-ascii characters from both your your startup disk
and hostname (see the Sharing panel in System Preferences)
and restart.

Ta da!

Comment: Did this work?  Both my startup disk, and hostname are single words with only ASCII characters - but I don't see symbols either.

Comment: This helped me with 2.x style crash logs. For 3.0 style I had to learn some perl and fix the symbolicate script. There's probably a definite version by now.

Comment: What do you mean "fix the symbolicate script?"  I'm stuck on this same issue without non-ascii characters in either place.  Instruments *used* to work for me until my Snow Leopard "upgrade."

Comment: The script that adds symbols to your stack traces is called "symbolicatecrash". It's one of the least robust pieces of code I've ever seen. It uses spotlight to [fail to] find your .dSYM, ignoring the one in your app dir, the current dir, etc. It was incorrectly quoting shell chars when I fixed my version (this was after the non-ascii work around). If you're comfortable with perl you can debug it, or just google symbolicatecrash+snowleopard. Maybe someone's fixed it good.

Answer (score 13):

For iOS 4.0 and higher, the way to fix symbols and turn those useless memory addresses into beautiful file names, function names and line numbers is as follows:

1. In Xcode, go to Run -> Run with Performance Tool and choose your instrument
2. After Instruments loads, hit the Stop button to stop recording. Go to File -> Re-Symbolicate Document.
3. In the new window, click Path and click the plus (+) button to add a new path. Navigate to the folder containing your project file and click Open. Click Symbolicate.
4. Profit!

I was looking for this for a good month before I finally came upon the solution. I hope this helps some of you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I couldn't get anything other similar questions suggested.  This worked perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me - as with others I could not get any of the other answers to work

Answer (score 8):

I saw this happen, but on a different configuration.  In Snow Leopard 10.6.1, Xcode 3.2, Instruments 2.0, I wasn't getting any symbols in Leaks when running iPhone OS 3.0 in the simulator.  Searching in Apple's iPhone developer forums revealed that this was a known issue with the iPhone 3.0 SDK (that was being worked on), and switching the active SDK to 3.1 was a workaround.  Sure enough, it worked for me!

Comment: I had the same issue and similarly switching the active SDK to iPhone 3.1 worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Project** > **Edit Project Settings**

Choose **Debug** target

Click **Build** Tab

Make sure **Strip Linked Product** is unchecked

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile in debug mode and make the symbol files available?

Answer (score 1):

If your build target directory starts with "." (e.g. I was using ".xcode-build") then the .dsym files will not be found. For my case, changing the build directory to be "xcode-build" fixed the problem and now all my application's symbols show up in stack traces!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out I had set the build directory to /tmp/xcode. Changing this back to the default fixed the problem. This was with Xcode 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.5.2 - Instruments 4.5 
Once i have set default Debug location to Legacy it started showing

Go to  File ----> Project Settings ----> Advanced  ---Select Legacy

[image: Debug Location ---Legacy Settings]