# Problem with finding leak code

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

I am using xcode 3.2 and I have leaks in my app but how can I find the line in my code which is leaking?? In earlier version of xcode I just used to double click on the object in the instrument which used to show the xcode with pointing the line with the leak. But in the 3.2 version I am not able to do that. 
Please anyone tell me how to find the line where memory is leaking?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instruments in XCode 3.2 has changed - but only for the better. It should be even *easier* to drill down to the suspect code. What behaviour are you seeing when you trying to "double click on the object"?

Comment: its show me assembly code which i dont understand.

Comment: Are you using a debug build?
It should show you the whole stack - with your code at some points and framework code at others. You should be able to see the source for your code. If you're using a release build you'll probably get strange symbol names for the methods themselves, but if you double click on them you should still get code.
Below the stack listing you'll see a slider. Slide it more to the left (but not all the way) to filter out most of the framework code.

Comment: btw, I'm just finishing off a new blog post covering some techniques to help you avoid getting the leaks in the first place. Watch for it here in the next day or so: www.levelofindirection.com

Answer (score 0):

You're probably working on 10.6, then you can use the extremely cool Build & Analyze feature (shift+cmd+a or in the menu Build->Build & Analyze).

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but doesn't answer the posters question. Personally I find the LLVM analyser misses a lot - so it's best to use *both* tools.

Comment: I have used it already. Analyser is not showing me the leaks but instruments is showing me leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments on your question, you might also find this helpeful (it was top link on the "Related" list on the right hand side of this page):

[Instruments Leaks - Not showing my source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728088/instruments-leaks-not-showing-my-source-code)